# Namespace geral para classe mapeada

Tags: java, xml, web-service, namespace, xsd

alguém poderia me ajudar com essa dúvida?

Com base em um XML de resultado de um WebService (OBIEE) gerei um XSD em um [conversor online](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html) e com esse XSD gerei a classe mapeada por meio do comando `xjc`.

Quando eu tentava jogar o resultado em XML na classe gerada (via unmarshaller do JAXB) ocorria o seguinte erro:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset", local:"rowset"). Expected elements are <{}rowset>
```

Esse erro era gerado devio a presença do atributo `xmlns` na primeira linha do XML.

```
<rowset xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset" >
```

Acabei resolvendo esse erro colocando em todas as anotações `@XmlElement` e `@XmlType` o atributo `namespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset"` ex:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "rowset",  namespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset" )
```

Minha dúvida é: como resolver o problema sem precisar jogar namespaces em todas essas anotações? Há como definir esse namespace de uma forma mais geral?

#### XML

```
<rowset xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset" >
<Row>
    <Column0>1337.0</Column0>
    <Column1>TESTE1</Column1>
    <Column2>2015-02-01T00:00:00</Column2>
    <Column3>47367.0</Column3>
    <Column4>129598.0</Column4>
    <Column5>142231.0</Column5>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Column0>1337.0</Column0>
    <Column1>TESTE2</Column1>
    <Column2>2015-03-01T00:00:00</Column2>
    <Column3>224892.0</Column3>
    <Column4>1624674.0</Column4>
    <Column5>1289782.0</Column5>
</Row>
</rowset>
```

#### XSD Gerado

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="rowset">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Row" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element type="xs:float" name="Column0"/>
                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Column1"/>
                        <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="Column2"/>
                        <xs:element type="xs:float" name="Column3"/>
                        <xs:element type="xs:float" name="Column4"/>
                        <xs:element type="xs:float" name="Column5"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em uma primeira análise parece que você está buscando pela anotação [@XmlSchema](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html). Com essa anotação você pode mapear namespaces, prefixos, etc, inclusive a nível de pacotes (granularidade mais grossa).

Para se valer desse tipo de estratégia você deve criar um arquivo `package-info.java` dentro do pacote desejado e anotá-lo conforme suas necessidades.

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema (
    namespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset", 
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
)  
package meu.pacote;
```

Se você pretende usar o `xfc` continuamente (e.g., ficar atualizando o serviço e gerando novamente as classes), talvez valha a pena brincar um pouco com a estrutura do XSD, [JAXB Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbbf.html#bnbcl), etc; ainda mais nesse caso em que o XSD foi gerado automaticamente. Inclusive é bom verificar se você realmente necessita do *namespace* para conformar com o serviço.

Já tive que dar manutenção em *softwares* com cadeias super complexas de *jaxb bindings* (além  de infinitas *tasks* do ant) para limpar *namespaces*, incluir prefixos, deletar classes duplicadas, etc... Isso costuma virar uma bagunça. Muitas vezes o problema pode ser resolvido de forma bem mais limpa simplificando os XSDs (e eventualmente o *payload* esperado), mesmo serviços fora do seu controle muitas vezes são bem mais flexíveis e lenientes do que esperamos.

---

**Fonte:** [Java XML and JSON Binding](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado, Anthony.
Funcionou perfeitamente!